# Why joining all threads in one loop is different from starting and joining one thread at a time?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have prepared two threading examples to show. 
My goal is to create 10 threads, and make them run in parallel at the same time. Also, I want my application to wait for the execution of all threads before executing anything else.

---

On the first example, the threads are started and joined right away. This makes JVM wait for the thread that was just joined to finish, before adding another one to the array. **This is not the behavior I want.**

```
public void example1() throws InterruptedException{
        ExampleThread[] threads = new ExampleThread[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            threads[i] = new ExampleThread();
            threads[i].start();
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }
```

---

On the second example, all threads are started, and a separate loop joins them, one at a time. **This reproduces the behavior I want.**

```
public void example2() throws InterruptedException{
        ExampleThread[] threads = new ExampleThread[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            threads[i] = new ExampleThread();
            threads[i].start();
        }
        for (ExampleThread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
```

---

Questions:

- Is JVM actually running all `join` methods at once?
- Is it waiting for the first `join` method to resolve before calling the other?
- Is this a reliable way to achieve the behavior I described? (besides ExecutorService, that might be better)

I am trying to understand the standard behavior of java threads. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Each call to `join()` blocks until the thread terminates.

Comment: A very useful tool is Javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-- - If you do not know what something does, read about it

Comment: Why is waiting for an answer after each letter different to sending ten letters first and waiting for answers afterwards?

Comment: @Holger Amazing analogy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`join()` blocks until the thread terminates (as @shmosel said). So this means in your first example, `threads[i+1]` won't get created until `threads[i]` completes.

In your second example, all threads are created and run in parallel, and then you wait for each to complete.